# ¿Qué diferencia existe entre <td> y <th>?

Tags: html-tabla, table

Tengo una duda acerca de la diferencia que existe entre la etiqueta `td` y `th` en  una tabla de `HTML`. Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme, muchas gracias.

Comment: La etiqueta th se utiliza para la primera fila de una tabla donde se suele poner el nombre del campo que va en las filas siguientes, que, por supuesto, esas son td.
Espero haberte resuelto la duda, a mi tambien me pasaba al principio, pero es fácil de entender. Saludos.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/td ---- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/th

Answer (score 4):

El `td` es usado para el cuerpo de tu tabla, mientras que el `th` son las que sirven para dar un resalto al titulo de cada columna de tu tabla (Generalmente se pone en negrita el texto por defecto).